# Select and execute the MIDI files displayed on QListWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, midi, qlistwidget

How to select and execute the MIDI files shown QListWidget in Qt so it can be played by a MIDI player?

I've made ​​a MIDI file player, but can only play songs that are determined directly from the source code. My Source Code still can not select from the table shown by QListWidget.Here is the source code for QListWidget and the integration of midi player with a menu created with Qt.

```
<pre>
gbe::gbe(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::gbe)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QDir myPath("/home/prom/playlist/");


    myPath.setFilter((QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot));
    myPlaylist = myPath.entryList();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(myPlaylist);}


void gbe::on_btnPlay_clicked()
{
    process.kill();
    process.start("/home/prom/QTGBE/gbe/midiplayer", QStringList() << "/home/prom/playlist/coldplay-magic.mid");

}



<code>
```

Please be specific in yout answer i will appreciate that,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Connect the [itemActivated(QListWidgetItem *)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemActivated) signal of your QListWidget object to a slot declared in your gbe class.  In your slot's method-body, call the text() method of the QListWidgetItem that was passed to it as an argument to find out what file that QListWidgetItem is representing.  Play that file.